# Preventing a service from starting on bootup on Android

Tags: android, service

Is it possible to prevent a service from starting when Android starts up by pressing some kind of key combination on the device?

Comment: You cannot. This link might be helpful: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/how-can-i-stop-applications-and-services-from-running